# How to clean-up email?

Tags: email, character-encoding

i got email with such symbols in html code, as: 3D, =BB, =, =A0 . How to get normal email? Please write code on PHP that givs normal html Code. Thanks.

Comment: Are these emails that you're sending or that you're receiving? ie are you asking for help with a programming issue or with configuring your email client? And whichever of those it is, you haven't told us anything about the software in question. It's not going to be possible to even attempt to answer the question without a lot more info.

Comment: this emails are that i receiving. i am ask to help me you with programming on PHP program to give right email html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a software library that implements the RFC-2045 rules for you. See particularly 'quoted printable' in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt.

Comment: what about PHP and their classes?